# cURL request works, but not an equivalent NSURLSession request

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession, nsurlrequest

This cURL gives me a good result on the console:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" https://myusername:mypassword@somehost.com/someroute
```

But this iOS code generates a 404

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL urlWithString:@"https://myusername:mypassword@somehost.com/someroute"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
request.HTTPMethod = @"GET";
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
[[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    // here, data is nil, there's no error, but the api returns 404
}] resume];
```

I know about transport security settings in iOS, but I thought those pertain only to http requests.  Can someone suggest what I might be doing wrong in iOS given that the cURL works fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic authentication credentials should be attached in the header.

Swift3:

```
let raw = "myusername:mypassword"
let encoded = raw.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii)!
let value = "Basic \(encoded.base64EncodedString())"
```

ObjC (not tested)

```
NSString *raw = @"myusername:mypassword";
NSData *encoded = [raw dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [encoded base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]];
[request setValue:value forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

Alternatively you can also verify the `Authorization` header using `curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "authorization: <value>" https://somehost.com/someroute`

Comment: Exactly. And as an added info: I assume cURL is internally doing basically just that. The fact you can put the username and password like that "into" the URL is just for convenience. At least you won't get a valid NSURLRequest from the same string cURL accepts.

Comment: I know you're not supposed to say 'thank you' on this site, but THANK YOU.